# Yii :: get controller actions specified by actions()

Tags: php, yii

I have controllers with next accessRules:

```
  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
      array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('login','logout'),
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
      array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('index'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
      ),
      array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('users'),
        'expression'=>'$user->getState(\'role\')==0',
      ),
      array('deny',
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

All actions (in all controllers) specified by actions() method:

```
  public function actions()
  {
    return array(
      'index'=>$this->module->getName().'.controllers.main.IndexAction',
      'login'=>$this->module->getName().'.controllers.main.LoginAction',
      'logout'=>$this->module->getName().'.controllers.main.LogoutAction',
    );
  }
```

Is there a chance to get controllers/actions list depends on current user permissions?
I want to build a nav menu with list of all controllers and their actions, something like this:

1. **Controler1** `(show only if current user have permissions to access it)`

   - **Controler1/action1** `(show only if current user have permissions to access it)`
   - **Controler1/action2** `(show only if current user have permissions to access it)`
2. **Controller2** `(show only if current user have permissions to access it)`

   - **Controler2/action1** `(show only if current user have permissions to access it)`
   - **Controler2/action2** `(show only if current user have permissions to access it)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the access rules if they are declared in your controllers.

You probably have to use Yii's Role Based Access Control (RBAC) and save your access rules externally, probably in the database. Read here for more information: [Yii Documentation - role based access control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control)

There is also a quite capable Yii extension called Rights, which provides a backend for RBAC.

This might seem like overkill for the moment, but RBAC is unmatched in flexibility. You can create user roles and assign operations to the roles very granularly.

If you use it, you can check access like `Yii::app->user->checkAccess('post.create')`, so exactly what you need for such a menu. But I don't think you can get a list of all available actions out of the box, but this is probably something you can relatively easily extend.